# нужно удалить запятые из страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

как удалить запятые? Появляются из-за того что такси это элементы массива
[image: страница HTML]

```
for (let i = 0; i <= (names.length-1); i++){
    if (unlock) {popupText.innerHTML += `
    <div class="popup__data-user">
      <img src="${pictures[i]}" alt="" class="profie-picture">
      <p class="username">${(names[i])}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="popup__tasks">
      <div class="popup__tasks-block">
        <div class="popup-tasks">${tasksAll[i].length > 1 ? 
          tasksAll[i].map(element => `<div class="task">${(element == undefined ? "Private Task" : element)}</div>`) : 
          `<div class="not_tasks">НЕТ ЗАДАЧ</div>`}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    `}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`` tasksAll[i].map(element => `<div class="task">${(element == undefined ? "Private Task" : element)}</div>`) `` на выходе мы получаем массив, если массив привести к строке, элементы будут разделены запятой. Вы можете воспользоваться методом `.join()` и в качестве аргумента указать пустую строку `.join('')`, мы получим на выходе строку из элементов массива разделенные пустой строкой.

```js
tasksAll[i].map(element => `<div class="task">${(element == undefined ? "Private Task" : element)}</div>`).join('')
```